# Freeing int pointer to pointer array works fine alone, but crashes in main program

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

This code snippet works fine on its own , but once I integrate it to my complete `main()` function, I get issues with `free(0`ing, sometimes failing at the first iteration, sometimes failing at a random I and sometimes when I try to free the `int` pointer pointer.

```
int main()
{
    int** GPRIListedCoords = calloc(sizeof(int*), GPRIMaxVal);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < GPRIMaxVal; i++)
        GPRIListedCoords[i] = calloc(sizeof(int) , 2);
    for( i = 0; i < GPRIMaxVal; i++ )
        free(GPRIListedCoords[i]);
    free(GPRIListedCoords);
    return 0;
}
```

I create / free the char pointers ( to pointers ) in the same way with no issues.

I tried catching any null pointers, but I'm not getting any.

GDB Stack info: http://i.snag.gy/Z3ZqV.jpg

Comment: `but once I add it to my main program I get issues with freeing`  What are you doing in your main program between the time you allocate and the time you delete?  That is what you should focus on.

Comment: @amdixon what? then the first `for` loop?

Comment: Nothing. Really, nothing. Unless you count printf for debugging.

Comment: @SouravGhosh removed as not relevant

Comment: In this program I defined it as 12, but in the main program it's a variable which is calculated at the start of the program.

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"?

Comment: Crashes horribly. Stopped working. Then I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: To all the people saying "there's nothing wrong with the program", you really need to look at the man page for calloc.  The first parameter is supposed to be the count and the second parameter is supposed to be the size.

Comment: I tried using malloc litereally replaceing the , with a * getting similiar results.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes horribly"?  Is there a core dump or a stack trace?  What is the exception?  Also, we can't divine the problem with your code when you don't show it to us.

Comment: http://i.snag.gy/VVQcx.jpg I'm not really well versed in things like "Core dump" and "Stack trace", time to google.

Comment: Or run it in the debugger.  When it crashes, the debugger should stop at the line that throws the exception.

Comment: DEVC++ Shows where it crashes in ASM, not really that useful. I know where it crashes since I encapsulated it with printfs.

Comment: The debugger **will** give you a stack trace.  It **will** tell you the value of the pointer(s) that you free.

Comment: Are you sure DEVC++ supports ( or has one built in ) it? All I get is "Program received SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." and this http://i.snag.gy/B5xAq.jpg.

Comment: I managed to find a stray fault in my ( main ) program with the GDB debugger, this thing's amazing. Thanks for the help and time guys!

Answer (score 1):

This code sample looks fine. I think the problem is in the other case, where you *do* something with the allocated pointers. as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) of `free()` (emphasis mine)

> `void free(void *ptr);`
>
> The `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, **which must have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`**. Otherwise, or if `free(ptr)` has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs. If ptr is `NULL`, no operation is performed.

So, in that case, if the `calloc()`-ed pointer is changed, you'll face [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can use a debugger (like, `gdb` on linux) to inspect the allocated memory locations and see if the pointer is changed or not.

Comment: Hi sourav, thanks for the help yesterday. I don't do anything with it yet in my main program which is odd...

Comment: @Nos maybe then you can show your _problematic_ function.

Comment: Problematic function? What do you mean? It crashes in the for loop freeing the int pointer most of the time.

Comment: @Nos I mean show us the code _where_ it is crashing.

Comment: for( i = 0; i < GPRIMaxVal; i++ )
   free(GPRIListedCoords[i]);

Comment: @Nos not here, edit your question and add the _complete_ code where its is crashing. and by _complete_ I mean a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___

Comment: The problem is is that I'm unable to, I verified multiple times that the variables are set correctly, the only thing that's different is that it's run in a big program.

Comment: The code runs flawlessly when I comment the code, but once I uncomment... http://i.snag.gy/ayA2h.jpg

Comment: @Nos how you can be so sure that problem is coming from _this_ block only? did you try using the debugger, like `gdb`?

Comment: It kinda has to as it's not affected by the other code and it's not affecting other code. I, apparantly it's called wolf fencing, wolf fenced it and the problem lies within the freeing part. I'll give GDB a shot.

Comment: O my, I think I'm in love with this debugger, it appears there was indeed a stray fault in my program coincidentally messing with the memory the code is using making me believe it's the code that's messing up. I removed the oddity and it works fine. Thanks Sourav.

Comment: To add, it works in the debugger but still crashes normally making me believe I've something called "race condition". Not sure how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine. However, if any part of your code is invoking undefined behaviour, then it could be damaging the internal malloc data structures, which is then causing a crash here.

Can you run your program on Linux? I find using valgrind (a Linux tool) can often shake out such bugs.

Comment: I can't really use linux now, but it seems useful indeed.